# Create NSDictionary from Dictionary Log printed by Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

Is it possible to create Dictionary from string data that log area of xcode display. Like

```
0 = {
"Key1" = "ABC";
};
1 = {
"Key1" = "DEF";
};
```

Comment: Could you provide more detail? I have no idea what you are trying to ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way whatsoever. The output of NSLog is purely for debugging purposes. You have no chance in hell reconstructing a dictionary from this. Don't even try.

What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I had data from another project (from web service can only accessible in other project) that i was including in another so i had only data as string from console. Anyways thanks i would have to hard code it

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me, as you are printing an array, containing two NSDictionary objects. 
When you write it out to the console, then you must know the object type (or can find it, using the debugger).

[image: Xcode debugger]

If its an array, you can loop through it, taking out the individual key and values, and adding them to a new NSMutableDisctionay, that then will contain a all keys/values. Just ensure that your keys are unique.

Comment: I had data from another project that i was including in another so i had only data as string from console. Otherwise i would have to hard code data that is alot.

Comment: If you want to include data that another project generated, the easiest way is often to use NSJSONSerialization to write it to a file in one project, and to read it from the same file in your project.